# Ignoring the nth appearance of a letter

Tags: java, arrays, string, indexof

I'm working on key columnar transposition cipher,

```
  for(int i = 0; i < column; i++){
      position = keyWord.indexOf(sorted_key[i]);
  }
```

Keyword is: `analyst`

sorted_key is: `{a, a, l, n, s, t, y}`

For letter 'a' it will only see index 0 (the first appearance) and it will always ignore any other occurrence of the letter. How to fix that?
I want it to see any other occurrence after the first one and so on

Thanks

Comment: do you want to iterate through the array?

Comment: @Peter Haddad  yes

Answer (score 1):

Here an example method

```
public static void findIndexes(){
    String searchableString = "don’t be evil.being evil is bad";
    String keyword = "be";

    int index = searchableString.indexOf(keyword);
    while (index >=0){
        System.out.println("Index : "+index);
        index = searchableString.indexOf(keyword, index+keyword.length())   ;
    }

}
```

Comment: I get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1